Increase swap memory in docker desktop
Swap memory is limited to 4GB. How do I increase this?




You can directly edit the %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json file, for example, by setting "SwapMiB": 8192. After making changes, restart Docker.

If you installed Docker with the WSL 2 backend (the default option), you need to create a .wslconfig file in your user directory. The file should have the following structure:


[wsl2]
memory=19GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2
swap=110GB

Source

On a Mac, it is at ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json

@mindlessgreen https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/mac/

After updating the settings.json and restarting docker, I see that the container still crashes as soon as it exceeds physically available RAM. So it doesn't seem like it's using the specified swap memory.
